# List LDAP groups from a group

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to list all groups that are a member of a group.  Each time I try to pull the Member Of attribute I get a list of the members, instead.

Essentially, I just want to query an AD group, and return the groups that it is a member of.  Any ideas on this?

Below is the code that I'm trying at the moment.

```
function getGroups($group){
  $ldap_host="My AD host";
  $ldap_dn="My AD DN";
  $user="my AD username";
  $password="my AD password";
  $keep=array("samaccountname","distinguishedname","memberOf");
  $ldap=ldap_connect($ldap_host) or die("Could not connect to LDAP");
  ldap_bind($ldap,$user.'@trusourcelabs.com',$password) or die("Could not bind to LDAP"); 
  $query='(&(memberOf=CN=accessRW,OU=Domain Security Groups,OU=Groups,OU=IT,OU=Corporate,OU=myOU,DC=myDomain,DC=com))';
  $results=ldap_search($ldap,$ldap_dn,$query);
  $entries=ldap_get_entries($ldap, $results);
  array_shift($entries);
  $output=array();
  $i=0;
  foreach($entries as $u){
    foreach($keep as $x){
      if(isset($u[$x][0])) $attrval=$u[$x][0]; else $attrval=NULL;
      $output[$i][$x]=$attrval."<hr />";
    }
    $i++;
  }

  return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out...  I needed to change this line:

```
$query='(&(memberOf=CN=accessRW,OU=Domain Security Groups,OU=Groups,OU=IT,OU=Corporate,OU=myOU,DC=myDomain,DC=com))';
```

to this:

```
$query='(&(member=CN=accessRW,OU=Domain Security Groups,OU=Groups,OU=IT,OU=Corporate,OU=myOU,DC=myDomain,DC=com))';
```

Looks like I was going about it backwards...

Comment: Only thing to keep in mind is this only will give you one layer of membership. If you want to support nested membership, you should look at the in chain matching rule query operator.